# Не понимаю почему здесь выводит ошибку surname is not defined, если это св-во определено, как так?

Tags: javascript, json, объекты

Я чисто хотел поэкспериментировать, глянуть как работает 2-ой опциональный аргумент в виде массива. Хотел, чтоб в итоге вывелось `{"name":"Nikita", "surname": "Ivanov", "age": 19, "friends":[{},{},{}]}`. Но при этом продолжается вывод ошибки, что вроде как св-во surname не определено, почему?

```js
let obj = {
    name: 'Nikita',
    surname: 'Ivanov',
    age: 19,
    friends: [
        { name: 'Kira', surname: 'Platt', age: 25 },
        { name: 'Victor', surname: 'Smith', age: 30 },
        { name: 'Victoria', surname: 'Blunt', age: 23 }
    ]
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, [name, surname, age, friends]));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оберните свойства в кавычки

```js
let obj = {
    name: 'Nikita',
    surname: 'Ivanov',
    age: 19,
    friends: [
        { name: 'Kira', surname: 'Platt', age: 25 },
        { name: 'Victor', surname: 'Smith', age: 30 },
        { name: 'Victoria', surname: 'Blunt', age: 23 }
    ]
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, ["name", "surname", "age", "friends"]));
```

Comment: Ага, понял. Так эти св-ва просто воспринимаются как названия переменных

Comment: А массив внутри св-ва friends выводит т.к. там одноименные св-ва получается

Comment: Да, второй аргумент JSON.stringify() определяет какие свойства могут содержаться в результату, так как у элементов в массиве есть те же свойства, то они выводиться в результате